Only json is returned in my Foody project
When I run my foody project and click on the categories on my web page, there is only json data on the displayed page. I want the recipe data to be in the cards. When I open the console, I get an error like this
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
:5229/api/dishes/GetDishesByCategory:1
DishByCategory.cshtml

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "DishesByCategory";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="tr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"]</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
</head>
<body>


    <div class="container mt-5 pt-5">
        <h2>@ViewData["Title"]</h2>
        <div class="row" id="dishesContainer">
            <!-- Yemekler burada JavaScript ile yüklenecek -->
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
            var categoryId = urlParams.get('categoryId');

            console.log("CategoryID:", categoryId);

            if (categoryId) {
                fetch(http://localhost:5229/api/Dishes/GetDishesByCategory?categoryId={}`)
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(data => {
                        var dishesContainer = document.getElementById('dishesContainer');
                        dishesContainer.innerHTML = ''; // Önceki içerikleri temizle

                        data.forEach(dish => {
                            var dishElement = document.createElement('div');
                            dishElement.classList.add('col-md-3', 'mb-4');

                            dishElement.innerHTML = `
                                        <div class="card">
                                            <img src="${dish.dishImages[0]}" class="card-img-top" alt="${dish.dishName}" />
                                            <div class="card-body">
                                                <h5 class="card-title">${dish.dishName}</h5>
                                                <p class="card-text">${dish.description}</p>
                                                <a href="/dish/${dish.dishId}" class="btn btn-primary">Detayları Gör</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    `;

                            dishesContainer.appendChild(dishElement);
                        });
                    })
                    .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>


HomeController
using Foody.Helpers;
using Foody.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Foody.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        // HomeController sınıfının yapıcısı, ILogger<HomeController> türünde bir günlükleme nesnesi alır
        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        // Ana sayfanın yüklenmesi için kullanılan eylem yöntemi
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            try
            {
                // API'ye GET isteği gönderir ve tüm kategorileri alır
                var response = ServiceManager.MakeRequest(HttpRequestType.GET, "Category/GetAllCategories");

                if (response != null && response.Result.HasValue && response.Result.Value)
                {
                    // API yanıtından kategorileri deseralize eder
                    var categories = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CategoryModel>>(response.Data.ToString());
                    // Kategorileri View'e gönderir
                    return View(categories);
                }
                else
                {
                    // API isteği başarısız olduğunda hata mesajını günlüğe kaydeder ve kullanıcıya gösterir
                    _logger.LogError($"API request failed with error: {response?.ErrorMessage}");
                    return Ok(response?.ErrorMessage ?? "Bilinmeyen bir hata oluştu.");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Bir hata oluşursa hata mesajını günlüğe kaydeder ve kullanıcıya gösterir
                _logger.LogError($"Bir hata oluştu: {ex.Message}");
                return Ok("İsteğinizi işleme alırken bir hata oluştu.");
            }
        }

        // Gizlilik politikası sayfasının yüklenmesi için kullanılan eylem yöntemi
        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // Hata sayfasının yüklenmesi için kullanılan eylem yöntemi
        [HttpPost("Home/Show")]
        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            // Hata sayfasını oluşturur ve hata ile ilgili bilgileri View'e gönderir
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
}


CategoryController

using Foody.Helpers;
using Foody.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Foody.Controllers
{
    public class CategoryController : Controller
    {
        // Ana sayfayı döndürür
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // Belirli bir kategoriye ait yemekleri getirir
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult DishesByCategory(int categoryId)
        {
            try
            {
                // Verilen kategori için yemekleri al
                var dishesResponse = ServiceManager.MakeRequest(HttpRequestType.GET, $"Dishes/GetDishesByCategory/{categoryId}");

                if (dishesResponse != null && dishesResponse.Result.HasValue && dishesResponse.Result.Value)
                {
                    // API yanıtından yemekleri deseralize eder
                    var dishes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DishModel>>(dishesResponse.Data.ToString());

                    // Yemekleri JSON olarak döner
                    return Json(dishes);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Yemekler alınamadığında hata mesajı döner
                    return Json(new { success = false, message = "Yemekleri almak başarısız oldu." });
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Bir hata oluştuğunda hata mesajı döner
                return Json(new { success = false, message = "İsteğinizi işleme alırken bir hata oluştu." });
            }
        }
    }
}


Displaying the page I am viewing in JSON format with cards

404 Not found error, means that your URL does not exist. Your GetDishesByCategory API is located in CategoryController. Should be "http://localhost:5229/api/Category/GetDishesByCategory?categoryId={}" instead of http://localhost:5229/api/Dishes/GetDishesByCategory?categoryId={}?

Also, you didn't pass the categoryId into the URL.

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: The model element passed to ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List1[Foody.Models.DishModel]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model element of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable 1[Food. Models.CategoryModel]'.
I updated the code and now I'm getting this error.

Your error is not reproducible. 1. I don't see your view applying the @model in the top of the page. 2. I don't see any of your API actions that return the instance of List<Foody.Models.DishModel> to the view. Would say this is another issue/problem compared to the original question. You should create another question post with the minimal, reproducible example for it.

Update the fetch URL in your JavaScript code to match the correct API endpoint and include the categoryId parameter.
fetch(`http://localhost:5229/api/Category/GetDishesByCategory?categoryId=${categoryId}`)

Verify that your CategoryController has an endpoint for GetDishesByCategory.
JavaScript code
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
var categoryId = urlParams.get('categoryId');

console.log("CategoryID:", categoryId);

if (categoryId) {
    fetch(`http://localhost:5229/api/Category/GetDishesByCategory?categoryId=${categoryId}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            var dishesContainer = document.getElementById('dishesContainer');
            dishesContainer.innerHTML = ''; // Clear previous content

            data.forEach(dish => {
                var dishElement = document.createElement('div');
                dishElement.classList.add('col-md-3', 'mb-4');

                dishElement.innerHTML = `
                    <div class="card">
                        <img src="${dish.dishImages[0]}" class="card-img-top" alt="${dish.dishName}" />
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">${dish.dishName}</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">${dish.description}</p>
                            <a href="/dish/${dish.dishId}" class="btn btn-primary">Detayları Gör</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                `;

                dishesContainer.appendChild(dishElement);
            });
        })
        .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
} });

Ensure your CategoryController has the correct method to handle the request:
[HttpGet("api/Category/GetDishesByCategory")]
public IActionResult GetDishesByCategory(int categoryId)
{
    try
    {
        var dishesResponse = ServiceManager.MakeRequest(HttpRequestType.GET, $"Dishes/GetDishesByCategory/{categoryId}");

        if (dishesResponse != null && dishesResponse.Result.HasValue && dishesResponse.Result.Value)
        {
            var dishes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DishModel>>(dishesResponse.Data.ToString());
            return Json(dishes);
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(new { success = false, message = "Failed to retrieve dishes." });
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Json(new { success = false, message = "An error occurred while processing your request." });
    }
}

By addressing these issues, your project should correctly display the recipe data in the cards.

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List1[Foody.Models.DishModel]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable1[Foody.Models.CategoryModel]'. Böyle bir hata aldım. Nasıl ilerlemeliyim?

To fix this error:

Ensure the correct model type in the view:

@model IEnumerable<Foody.Models.CategoryModel>

Update the controller to pass the correct model:

public IActionResult Index()
{
var categories = _context.Categories.ToList();
return View(categories);
}

Could the error be caused by something else? I applied these too but the error still remained.

It seems to be a type mismatch issue between the model and the view model. I recommend checking the type in the controller model and comparing it with the type in the view model. Make sure they match ..
